# Two player, one platform, online Steam games

Tags: steam

I am wondering if there are any Steam games that two players on one PC can play two players on another PC online? I know there are family sharing rules and such, just wondering if this is possible.

Comment: Most likely yes; unfortunately, the question isn't quite on the topic of the site, as it asks for a recomnendation. Maybe try the Stack Exchange chat rooms?

Comment: @john those require 20 rep

Comment: Voted up so he could have the rep to come chat.

Answer (score 1):

Never tried it, but Remote Play would probably do as you ask. https://store.steampowered.com/remoteplay

Then just look for games with the category [Split-Screen PVP](https://store.steampowered.com/search/?category2=39) or [Split-Screen Coop](https://store.steampowered.com/search/?category2=37)